# importar xls con texto enriquecido, con phpExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpmyadmin

Estoy buscando la forma de importar un xls con texto enriquecido a la base de datos del servidor a través de phpExcel. Algunas celdas del archivo contienen texto plano y otras texto enriquecido, con varios formatos en la misma celda.

Ya he chequeado la opción `getStyle()` y `getCellValue()` de [PHPexcel cannot reads styles from xls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979394/phpexcel-cannot-reads-styles-from-xls) pero no lo consigo.

- Mark Baker utiliza el `getStyle()` para extraer el estilo de una celda concreta ('B2'). Yo necesito extraer el contenido de todas, contengan o no texto enriquecido. Con `toArray()` recorro todo el xls.
- En la segunda opción utiliza `getCellValue()`. Esta instrucción me da el siguiente mensaje: **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::getCellValue()

¿Cómo hago para importar todo el contenido del excel manteniendo los estilos?

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta que enlazas debe estar desfasada ya que es de 2012.

toArray() sigue existiendo y devuelve un array con los datos de la página activa.

En la versión actual de phpExcel el código de la segunda opción sería algo como:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2')->getValue();
```

---

Para recorrer las distintas celdas puedes usar los diferentes "iterator" (rowiterator y columniterator).

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("test.xlsx");

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

echo '<table>' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    echo '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE); // This loops through all cells,
                                                       //    even if a cell value is not set.
                                                       // By default, only cells that have a value 
                                                       //    set will be iterated.
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        echo '<td>' . 
             $cell->getValue() . 
             '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</table>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Este es el ejemplo que aparece en: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md

Sobre cada objeto Cell puedes usar los metodos getValue y getStyle para obtener los datos que necesitas.